# How do I disable the circular slider buttons?

Tags: css, themes, prestashop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUrM7.png)

I have the 'Ebotic' theme installed in my Prestashop online store, but for some strange reason double buttons are enabled for the slider, I already tried to search for the classes defined in the css files of the theme but I cannot find the classes defined in those files

Comment: This is css: .owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span {
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 5px 7px;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=50);
    opacity: .5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #869791;
}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: With respect you should contact the author/vendor of the theme. You should have support in place as it is a premium theme.